# How to delete table data in object?

Tags: jquery, json, object

I can do edit operation in both table and object, but when I click delete button it gets delete in table only not in object. I insert `empobj` button to view table data, if I edit table data it stores in both table and object I am expecting delete operation also do the same. But when I click delete button, the table data only delete. After I click `empobj` button the deleted data shows in object, I want to know delete table data in object .

This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/N4N2x/56/):

```js
$("#adbut").click(function() {
  var nm = $("#nm").val();
  var f1 = $("#f1").val();
  var f2 = $("#f2").val();
  if (nm && nm != "") {
    var nEmpObj = {};
    nEmpObj.name = nm;
    nEmpObj.f1 = f1;
    nEmpObj.f2 = f2;
    fArr.push(nEmpObj);
    $("#list").append(constList(nEmpObj));
    $("#list").show();
    $("#add").hide();
  }

});
var nEmpObj = {};
var obj;


$("#cbut").click(function() {
  $("#add").hide();
});

$("#crt").click(function() {
  $("#add").show();
});
$("#obj").click(function() {
  alert(JSON.stringify(fArr));
});
$('.del').live('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  var parentTd = common.parent('td');
  var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {

    console.log(nEmpObj.fArr[0].name);
    if ((fArr[i].name) == (parentTr.find('td #name').html())) {

      delete fArr[i];
    }


  }

});

var common;

$("#et").live('click', function() {
  common = $(this);
  var parentTd = common.parent('td');
  var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
  var nombre = parentTr.find('td #name').html();

  var name = parentTr.find('td #name').html(),
    item1 = parentTr.find('td #field1').html(),
    item2 = parentTr.find('td #field2').html();
  nam.value = name;
  i1.value = item1;
  i2.value = item2;
  $("#edit").show();



});

$("#sv").live('click', function() {
  //  alert(fArr[0].name);

  var parentTd = common.parent('td');
  var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
  var nam = $('#nam').val(),
    i1 = $('#i1').val(),
    i2 = $("#i2").val();
  for (var i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
    //        alert(parentTr.find('td #name').html());

    if ((fArr[i].name) == (parentTr.find('td #name').html())) {

      fArr[i].name = nam;
      fArr[i].f1 = i1;
      fArr[i].f2 = i2;

    }


  }
  parentTr.find('td #name').html(nam);
  parentTr.find('td #field1').html(i1);
  parentTr.find('td #field2').html(i2);
  $("#edit").hide();

});


$("#cn").click(function() {
  $("#edit").hide();
});

function get_data() {

}
var fArr = [];

var constList = function(dta) {
  return $("<tr><td><span id='name'>" + dta.name + "</span></td><td><span id='field1'>" + dta.f1 + "</span></td><td><span id='field2'>" + dta.f2 + "</span></td><td><button class  = del>Delete</button><button id = et >Edit</button></td></tr>")
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block
}
.hide {
  display: none
}
.addDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B6A6A6;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #B6A6A6;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.table td {
  border: 1px solid #B6A6A6;
}
;
 .ed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B6A6A6;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="add" class="addDiv" style="display:none">
  <span>Add Details</span>
  <div><span>Name</span>
    <input id="nm" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div><span>Field1</span>
    <input id="f1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div><span>Feild2</span>
    <input id="f2" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="adbut" type="button" value="Add" />
    <input id="cbut" type="button" value="cancel"></input>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input id="crt" type="button" value="create" />
  <input id="obj" type="button" value="emp obj" />
</div>
<div id="dtaListing">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td>Item2</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table" id="list" style="display:none">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="edit" class="ed" style="display:none">
  <span>Edit Details</span>
  <div><span>Name</span>
    <input id="nam" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div><span>Item1</span>
    <input id="i1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div><span>Item2</span>
    <input id="i2" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="sv" type="button" value="Save" />
    <input id="cn" type="button" value="cancel"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: I can edit table data and store those data in both table and array of object.I Would like to do the same for delete button

Comment: You couldn't be more vague if you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. If you could re word it, it would help anyone finding this post but deleting from an object is easy. Let's say you have the below object.

```
var myObject = { thisParameter : "something"}
```

You could be then delete that parameter by running...

```
delete myObject.thisParameter;
```

Comment: Wizard My Question is, i can delete table data but it is stores in object.How to remove the data in object.

Comment: I am sorry if I search empobj I can't find anything related to programming. as well your question doesn't clarify what context table is in. Tables exist as entities in databases, HTML, and other languages that have completely different functionality. Can you please clarify.

Comment: @CodeWizard: `empobj` is the name of a variable in his code, so you won't get very far by searching for it on the internet.

Comment: use JSfiddle.net. The empobj is a button. You can see array of objects in alert box when u click that button.First create then add you can see data in table then press empobj button you can see array of object in alert box what stored in table.